# Create a generic typescript type that enforces a value of a field in a map is a value from another type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to create a generic type that enforces more specific constraints. With the following:

```
const TypeConfigName = ['config1', 'config2'] as const;
type TypeConfigName = (typeof TypeConfigName)[number];

const allConfigFields


type GroupNames<TName extends TypeConfigName> = Readonly<string[]>;

type Config<TName extends TypeConfigName> = {
  groupNames: GroupNames<TName>;
  fields: {
    [k: string]: { group: GroupNames<TName>[number] };
  };
};

const config1: Config<'config1'> = {
  groupNames: ['group1', 'group2'],
  fields: {
    field1: { group: 'group1' },
    field2: { group: 'group2' },
  },
};
```

The idea is that the type of `fields[fieldName].group` is enforced to be one of the values defined in `groupNames`.

The way I have it defined right now does not enforce that, group is allowed to be any string.

If possible i'd like the config to infer the constraint from itself, rather than having to define a separate map of TypeConfigName's to allowed GroupNames

Comment: `type GroupNames<TName extends TypeConfigName> = Readonly<string[]>;` doesn't make any sense at all

Comment: Why even have `TName extends TypeConfigName` as a generic if none of the fields of `Config<TName>` depend on it?  If you had some mapping from `TName` to the allowed group names then this would make sense, but you explicitly say you don't want to define such a map.  So then it seems like `Config` should be completely independent of `TName`.  Please [edit] to either make it obvious why that dependency exists (by showing use cases that demonstrate it) or remove it entirely and make `Config` not generic in `TName`, so that this is a [mre].

Comment: Like, if you remove the part about `TName`, then I'd say "you need `Config` to be generic in the type `G` of elements of `groupNames`, but you can write a generic function to infer that type without having to specify it, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WvxVkN).  Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?" but I can't say that because I don't know what's going on with `TypeConfigName` and how it relates to anything.

Comment: Apologies for that not being clear, the actual type I'm working with uses that generic but I (confusingly) simplified it to the point it's not relevant to the question I actually asked. Your playground does meet the needs I have

Comment: How would you extend that playground example to allow the fields to be optional?